# Density operator as a function of time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, notation, differentiation

Given the density operator $\rho = \sum_iw_i | \alpha^{i} \rangle \langle \alpha^{i}|$, how does the density operator change with time. Apparently I should get $$i \hbar \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \sum_{i}w_i(H| \alpha^{i}(t) \rangle \langle \alpha^{i}(t)| - | \alpha^{i}(t) \rangle  \langle \alpha^{i}(t)|H).$$ I am having difficulty getting this, it seems that I have to use Shrodingers equation on the $(| \alpha \rangle \langle \alpha|)$ since the intial population $w_i$ is constant in time, but I'm not sure how to differentiate this since $\langle \alpha|$ as I understand is a bra which is a functional in a sense, how does the product rule for differentiation apply then in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with
\begin{align}
i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}\vert{\alpha}\rangle &=H\vert\alpha\rangle
\end{align}
and take the adjoint
$$
-i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}\langle {\alpha}\vert  =\langle \alpha\vert H
$$
where $H^\dagger=H$ has been used.
Then simply use the product rule:
\begin{align}
i\hbar\frac{d}{dt} \left[\vert \alpha\rangle\langle\alpha\vert
\right]&=
\left[i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\vert \alpha\rangle\right]\langle\alpha\vert
+ \vert\alpha\rangle\left[i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\langle \alpha\vert\right]\, ,\\
&=\left[H\vert\alpha\rangle\right]\langle\alpha\vert - 
\vert\alpha\rangle
\left[ \langle\alpha\vert H\right]\, .
\end{align}

Comment: I have one other query that maybe you have some insight on. I posted [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329773/queries-of-proof-of-adiabatic-theorem-in-qm/329776#329776).